# Setting self.view.frame after going back does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I am setting the `UITableViewController`'s frame in `viewDidAppear` as follows:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 468.0);
```

The original frame height is `516.0`.

This works fine initially and the frame does change. However, when I go back to that view controller (it is in a `UINavigationController`), the frame does not change (says at `516.0` even though that line is indeed called when going back.

What is causing the frame to not change the second time the controller is shown and how do you rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear will not be called when you dismiss a modal view. Think of a modal view as a view on top on the view.

When you push or pop a view controller on/off a navigaction controller's stack, the usual viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear methods aren't called. If you want to ensure they're always called, just add the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol to your root view controller:

Comment: It is being called. I set a breakpoint on it and it is being called when I go back.

Answer (score 0):

It is occurred because of the autolayout. Untick the autolayout check box in xib or storyboard. Then it will work.